# SQL over clause - dividing partition into numbered sub-partitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, ranking-functions

I have a challenge, that I've come across at multiple occasions but never been able to find an efficient solution to. Imagine I have a large table with data regarding e.g. bank accounts and their possible revolving moves from debit to credit:

```
AccountId DebitCredit AsOfDate
--------- ----------- ----------
aaa       d           2018-11-01
aaa       d           2018-11-02
aaa       c           2018-11-03
aaa       c           2018-11-04
aaa       c           2018-11-05
bbb       d           2018-11-02
ccc       c           2018-11-01
ccc       d           2018-11-02
ccc       d           2018-11-03
ccc       c           2018-11-04
ccc       d           2018-11-05
ccc       c           2018-11-06
```

In the example above I would like to assign sub-partition numbers to the combination of AccountId and DebitCredit where the partition number is incremented each time DebitCredit shifts. In other words in the example above I would like this result:

```
AccountId DebitCredit AsOfDate   PartNo
--------- ----------- ---------- ------
aaa       d           2018-11-01      1
aaa       d           2018-11-02      1
aaa       c           2018-11-03      2
aaa       c           2018-11-04      2
aaa       c           2018-11-05      2

bbb       d           2018-11-02      1

ccc       c           2018-11-01      1
ccc       d           2018-11-02      2
ccc       d           2018-11-03      2
ccc       c           2018-11-04      3
ccc       d           2018-11-05      4
ccc       c           2018-11-06      5
```

I cannot really figure out how to do it quickly and efficiently. The operation has to be done daily on a tables with millions of rows.

In this example it is guaranteed that we will have consecutive rows for all accounts. However, of course the customer might open an account the 15th in the month and/or close his account the 26th.

The challenge is to be solved on an MSSQL 2016 server, but a solution that would work on 2012 (and maybe even 2008r2) would be nice.

As you can imagine there's no way of telling whether there will only be debit or credit rows or whether the account will be revolving each day.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that consecutive rows (for a particular account) are for consecutive days?

Comment: your output is contradictory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have sql server 2012+, you can use lag() and a window summation to get this:

```
select *,sum(PartNoAdd) over (partition by AccountId order by AsOfDate asc) as PartNo_calc
from
(
    select *,
    case when DebitCredit=lag(DebitCredit,1) over (partition by AccountId order by AsOfDate asc) then 0 else 1 end as PartNoAdd
    from t 
)t2
order by AccountId asc, AsOfDate  asc
```

At the inner query, `PartNoAdd` checks if the previous DebitCard for this account is the same. If it is, it returns 0 (we should add nothing), else it returns 1.

Then the outer query sums all the `PartNoAdd` for this Account.

Answer (score 6):

you can do this with a recursive cte

```
; with
-- the purpose of `cte` is to generate running number in the order of AsOfDate
cte as
(
    select  AccountId, DebitCredit, AsOfDate, rn = row_number() over (partition by AccountId order by AsOfDate)
    from    tbl
),
-- this is the recursive CTE
rcte as
(
    -- anchor member. Starts with `PartNo 1`
    select  AccountId, DebitCredit, AsOfDate, rn, PartNo = 1
    from    cte
    where   rn  = 1

    union all

    -- recursive member. Incrememt `PartNo` if there is a change in debitcredit
    select  c.AccountId, c.DebitCredit, c.AsOfDate, c.rn,
            PartNo = case when r.DebitCredit = c.DebitCredit then r.PartNo else r.PartNo + 1 end
    from    rcte r
            inner join cte c    on  r.AccountId = c.AccountId
                                and r.rn        = c.rn - 1
)
select  *
from    rcte
order by AccountId, AsOfDate
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use dense rank

```
select *,dense_rank() over(partition by AccountId order by DebitCredit desc) as PartNo
from t
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as i see it not in this case. In case of account with id 'ccc', 2018-11-01, 2018-11-04, and 2018-11-08 would fall into the same "bucket", even though they belong to different "peroids"